# Ghost Informix Instances In Windows

Tags: installation, informix

I am trying to install Informix version 11.70 on Windows 7 64bit.  After a few attempts of installing and unstalling, I cannot create a instance called ol_informix1170.  When creating a new instance during installation, the default instance name keep showing ol_informix1170_3.  If I correct it to ol_informix1170, the program will tell me that the server name is already in use.

I've unstalled it, delete the directories, even looking into registry and delete anything with informix, but the problem persists.

Can someone please point out what I am missing?  The resource on the net is quite scarce, not much info turn up on searching informix alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\service`, Informix records the used instance number(s) in this text file.